# Stuck on the same updates; apt-get update doesn't seem to help

Tags: apt

For the past few days, I've logged onto my server and seen

`9 packages can be updated.`

So I `sudo apt-get update`. If I log out and right back in, I will once again see

`9 packages can be updated.`

This has been going on for a few days. How would I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run "sudo apt-get upgrade", update only refreshes the repos, not the packages

Comment: That appears to have done the trick, thanks. I was aware upgrade was another option, but I was worried it would try to upgrade my distro or something (I know 12.04, 12.04 is running stably for me, I have no desire to change).

Comment: to upgrade the full distro, you use sudo apt-get dist-upgrade